# How to reset my step length?

Tags: iphone, gps, health.app

I have had a new iPhone SE for a few weeks. It works fine, but in the "Health" app, my step length is approximately 0.6 m (1000 steps give a distance of 600 meters), which seems wrong (I used to have around 0.8 m with my previous phone). I also checked with the distance on my companion's iPhone : my iPhone correctly measures steps, but not distances.

Is there any way to reset this ?

BTW : yes, I have allowed the "Motion Calibration & Distance" option in the "Privacy" setting.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately Apple does not provide this option in the health app.

There is an app that does though called Fitbit which tracks your steps and you can input your step length. This feature does not require a tracker.

Link to app in AppStore:
Fitbit by Fitbit, Inc. https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/fitbit/id462638897?mt=8

Answer (score 0):

Apple has a [support page dedicated to calibrating the Watch](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204516). The only way to reset the stride is to recalibrate the Watch.

> You can calibrate your Apple Watch to improve the accuracy of your distance, pace, and calorie measurements. Calibrating your watch can also help it learn your fitness level and stride, which improves accuracy when GPS is limited or unavailable.

## Reset your calibration data

If you want to reset your calibration data, open the Apple Watch app on your iPhone. Tap the `My Watch` tab, then tap `Privacy > Motion & Fitness > Reset Calibration Data`.

Comment: I've done this regularly with good effect. In the fall and winter I run different paths with different traction and both walk and run change a bit. The only downside of a reset is you want to pick two or three representative walks and runs soon after the reset.

Comment: The question I asked was for an **iPhone**, not an Apple Watch.

Comment: My mistake, I incorrectly assumed you were talking about the Watch.  Sorry.

Comment: The question was asked about the iPhone not the watch

Comment: @DManokhin You're repeating a comment the OP left 2 years ago.  What's your point?